# How to ignore the file name in which redirecting the output of file listing?

Tags: linux, files, find

When I am using the command to find all the files in a directory and its sub directories and redirecting the output into a file result.txt, then in result.txt file I am getting all the files including result.txt but I don't want result.txt.

like I am doing

```
find . -type f > allfiles.txt
```

in result I am getting as

```
./test1/test3/file4
./test1/file3
./test2/test4/file6
./test2/file5
./allfiles.txt
```

How to avoid that?

Comment: Why not just redirect to a file in a different directory? `find . -type f >/tmp/allfiles`?

Comment: The `> file` bit is handled by the shell before the program is started, so if you don't want that to happen then, you cannot pipe it to there in this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply, don't put your allfiles.txt file into the same directory you're runing find for. Put it somewhere else, like:

```
find . -type f > /tmp/allfiles.txt
```

Or if it has to be in the same directory, filter it our with grep:

```
find . -type f | grep -vxF ./allfiles.txt > allfiles.txt
```

(assuming there are no other files called `./foo\n./allfiles.txt` for instance)

Comment: See edit with -x and -F to catch even fewer files (still potentially a problem with filenames containing newline characters as noted).

Answer (score 16):

Here with `find` specifically, you can do:

```
find . ! -path ./allfiles.txt -type f > allfiles.txt
```

More generally, you can delay the creation of the output file until after the command has returned using moreutils' `sponge` command:

```
ls -lRA | sponge allfiles.txt
```

Though that does mean storing the whole output in memory.

If moreutils is not installed (it's generally not by default), you can implement `sponge` as:

```
sponge() {
  perl -0777 -e '$text=<STDIN>;
                 open STDOUT, ">", shift or die$!;
                 print $text' -- "$@"
}
```

Comment: `sponge` may not be available.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, true. See edit.